# Unable to logout from guest session on Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: lightdm, 20.04, guest-session

I have Xubuntu 20.04 installed on a couple of my AMD64 machines, and in each case I've edited:

/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-guest.conf

do that it now contains:

```
[Seat:*]
allow-guest=true
```

And I'm now able to satisfactorily login to a guest session, but when I attempt to logout I get:

```
Receiver error while trying to log out
GDBus.Error.org .. Type of message "(yb)", does not match expected type "(b)"
```

[image]

Comment: I tested the guest session on Ubuntu groovy (don't have any Xubuntu install available) but couldn't reproduce the issue. Maybe a Xubuntu bug. OTOH, considering that the security scheme of guest session is broken, it may be hard to find someone willing to spend time on it. You [may want to try](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+filebug), though.

Answer (score 0):

I have reported the issue [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-session/+bug/1855350)

Workaround:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf.bak
```

I am not aware of any negative side effects of the workaround.